# common.logging not printing log messages after upgrade to log4j 2.17

Tags: java, spring, maven, log4j, log4j2

I upgraded log4j from 1.x to 2.17 successfully but there is no log messages printing.
I debug and found org.apache.commons.logging (already exist in .java files) is not printing any log messages but if I change this to org.slf4j.logging it will work.
So one solution is change the package in all 100s of java file, before going with that I am looking any solution which will print log message with existing code.

updated log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>

    <Appenders>
        <Console name="CONSOLE">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="[%t] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSSZ} %-10p [%l] : %m%n"></PatternLayout>
        </Console>

        <RollingFile name="FILE" fileName="${sys:catalina.home}/logs/xyz.log"
            filePattern="${sys:catalina.home}/logs/xyz-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%t] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSSZ} %-10p [%l] : %m%n"></PatternLayout>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="70 MB"></SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="200">
                <Delete basePath="${sys:catalina.home}/logs" maxDepth="1">
                    <IfFileName glob="xyz*-*-*-*.log"></IfFileName>
                    <IfLastModified age=100d"></IfLastModified>
                </Delete>
            </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        </RollingFile>


    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <AsyncRoot level="${sys:log4j.priority}" includeLocation="true">
            <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE" level="debug" />
            <AppenderRef ref="FILE" level="debug"></AppenderRef>
        </AsyncRoot>
    </Loggers>


</Configuration>
```

dependencies I modified:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.17.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
      <version>2.17.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-jcl</artifactId>
      <version>2.17.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

one of the Java class:

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

public class controller{
 protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());
 ......
}
```

Comment: May also show the code of how you are instantiating LOG

Comment: Enable JCL diagnostics by setting `-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.diagnostics.dest=STDERR` as JVM option: you might have  multiple `LogFactory` implementations in your classpath and JCL might use the wrong one. You might also have drop-in replacements for JCL on your classpath, such as `jcl-over-slf4j`.

Comment: I removed the log4j-jcl dependency looks like it's working, testing it. Thank you Piotr